# datatable <p:ajax> exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Trying to do some simple primefaces datatable ajax work and get the following exception:

javax.servlet.ServletException: /default.xhtml @17,76  Parent not an instance of ClientBehaviorHolder: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@5fdb7adc

I'm using primefaces 3.3.1. My .xhtml code is here (I copied some of it from the primefaces site to see if I could get this working), anybody got any ideas?

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >    

 <h:head>

 </h:head>
 <h:body>
 <center>
 <h:form id="form">

 <p:dataTable id="personTable" var="client" value="#{tableBean.persons}" 
             selection="#{tableBean.person}" selectionMode="single">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onUserSelect}"   
                update=":form:displayf" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />  

            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" 
                listener="#{tableBean.onUserUnselect}" 
                update=":form:displayf" />

    <f:facet name="header">
        Click "View" button after selecting a row to see details
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Name">
        #{client.name}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Address">
        #{client.address}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Phone" >
        #{client.phone}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
            showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  

<h:panelGrid id="displayf" columns="2" cellpadding="4">


        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.person.name}" />

        <h:outputText value="Address:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.person.address}" />

        <h:outputText value="Phone:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.person.phone}" />

</h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>

</h:form>

</center>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you try to change line 17, changing this `update=":form:displayf"` to this `update="@all"`?

Comment: Did so and no go. Good idea though.

Comment: So I think you better posting both `.xhtml` and `ManagedBean` right there on [Primefaces forum](http://http://forum.primefaces.org/index.php). They use to be faster to answer. It looks like you're facing something related to PrimeFaces version.

Comment: @axcdnt: how exactly did you think that using `@all` would possibly solve the problem..?

Comment: Dave, this exception suggests that you've an older version of PrimeFaces somewhere in the runtime classpath which is conflicting with 3.3.1. To exclude the one and other, doublecheck your entire runtime classpath for duplicate PrimeFaces JAR files.

Comment: @BalusC it was a try. I've had different problems with the element to be updated before.

Comment: @axcdnt: I really don't see how a wrong `update` would ever throw exactly this exception...

Comment: Okay, I built a brand new version of the program in Eclipse and got a new SelectEvent error (suggesting that there was a conflict) which is:    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent
 at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
 at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

Comment: I'm going to put a new question on the site for the SelectEvent error since it is a new error. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: @Dave as Balus mentioned it looks like a build issue, no need another question. Simply try to import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent into your bean if you can not it means you dont have 3.3.1  if you can then make sure you have removed oldest version because ajax calls handled by oldest one.